# how to call a function after completion of setting a state variable of a functional component in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a state variable where it is continuously changing and after the final state change I have to call a function which removes duplicate from final state variable.

while I am setting state variable, I am using prevstate to merge the present state value

code is below

```
const setevent = async(events) =>{
    await setevent((prevstate) => [...prevstate,...events])
}
```

I have to call a function using final event variable as props.

how can I do this?

actually I have seen a approach where after completing the setstate it is like below

```
const setevent = async(event) =>{
    await setevent(event,() => {
      //calling the function which I need
      getunique(event)
  })
}
```

but I cant make it work because I am already using prevState.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use useEffect and monitor your events changing state , when it reached its condition then you can trigger your function like this .

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(myCondition)
      getunique(something)
  },[events]);
```

Comment: I tried this also but In getUnique function I am passing events as props and I am changing the state variable  of the events. so after changing the events state again the use effect will call and it leads to infinite loop. how to avoid this?

Comment: that is why there is an IF before calling getUnique function you only call that function in every events change if your condition is met (which i dont know what is exactly)